# django passing id of the first saved form to the second form

Tags: django

My model has one to many relationships, when the user saves the first forms he will navigate to another form and the user should be able to fill up the second form and save it. Because it is a one-to-many relationship I want to pass the id instance of the first saved entry to the second form. However, when I fill up the second form and try to save it the data for the second form is not saved. I am not sure what I am doing wrong causes the data on the second form not to be saved.

view.py that saves the first forms

```html
ef add_bank_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BankForm(request.POST)
        natural_person_form = NaturalPpersonPform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        OwnShares = OwnSharesInOtherCompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and natural_person_form.is_valid():
            form = form.save()
            natural_person = natural_person_form.save(commit=False)
            natural_person.domesticbank = form
            natural_person.save()
            share = OwnShares.save(commit=False)
            share.domesticbank = form
            share.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/add_source_of_income')
            

    else:
        form = BankForm()
        natural_person_form = NaturalPpersonPform()
        OwnShares = OwnSharesInOtherCompanyForm()
    return render(request, 'add_domestic_bank.html',
                  {'form': form, 'natural_person_form': natural_person_form, 'OwnShares': OwnShares})
```

view.py that saves the second form

```html
def add_source_of_income(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        get_bank_id = DomesticBank.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
        form = SourceOfIncomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=get_bank_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/DisplayBankRisk')

    else:

        form = SourceOfIncomeForm()
    return render(request, 'add_income_source.html',
                  {'form': form})
```

```html
class DomesticBank(models.Model):
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    subsidiary_or_branch = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    home_country = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateField('Date Published', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bank_name


class NaturalPerson(models.Model):
    domesticbank = models.ForeignKey(DomesticBank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    natural_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    upload_passport_copy = models.FileField(upload_to='Passport/PDF', null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.natural_person_name


class OwnSharesInOtherCompany(models.Model):
    domesticbank = models.ForeignKey(DomesticBank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_of_companies = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    business_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    country = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    upload_legal_documents = models.FileField(upload_to='LegalDocument/PDF', null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initiating the wrong instance in your second form here `get_bank_id = DomesticBank.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]`. You are using a DomesticBank instance instead of a NaturalPerson instance.

Since you have a one-to-many relationship between banks and persons, you cannot use the bank id to identify a particular person (there could be several persons linked to the same bank).

Instead you can pass the person ID as an argument to your second view.

**Views.py**

```
def add_bank_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BankForm(request.POST)
        natural_person_form = NaturalPpersonPform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        OwnShares = OwnSharesInOtherCompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and natural_person_form.is_valid():
            form = form.save()
            natural_person = natural_person_form.save(commit=False)
            natural_person.domesticbank = form
            natural_person.save()
            share = OwnShares.save(commit=False)
            share.domesticbank = form
            share.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('income_source', kwargs={'person_id': natural_person.id})
    else:
        form = BankForm()
        natural_person_form = NaturalPpersonPform()
        OwnShares = OwnSharesInOtherCompanyForm()
        return render(request, 'add_domestic_bank.html',
                  {'form': form, 'natural_person_form': natural_person_form, 'OwnShares': OwnShares})

def add_source_of_income(request, person_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        person = NaturalPerson.objects.get(id=person_id)
        form = SourceOfIncomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=person)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/DisplayBankRisk')
    else:
        form = SourceOfIncomeForm()
        return render(request, 'add_income_source.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
#change the path for your second view to include the parameter:

 path(/add_source_of_income/<int:person_id>', views.add_source_of_income, name='income_source'),
```